# call function from another class

Tags: php

im trying to call a function from another class called square function area to cuboid class.

```
abstract class Shapes
{
protected $name;
protected $colour;

function __construct($n, $c)
{
    $this->name   = $n;
    $this->colour = $c;
}
```

thankyou!

Comment: where is your printShape method ?

Comment: What is the purpose of passing in "Square" to your Square class and "Cuboid" to your Cuboid class?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. ive updated my main post. ive added the code right at the top. print function is in abstract class

Comment: purpose is so that the user doesn't have to enter the values again after they have worked out a square to work out a cuboid. it will give them an option to work out the cuboid if they want to without entering the details

Comment: Two independent objects/classes cannot and shouldn't share data. Your cuboid could implement a method to convert from a square: `$c1 = Cuboid::fromSquare($s1);`

Comment: @deceze , thanks for your reply. how would i go around using that function. if you can kindly help me please.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: At least you should fix this method:

```
function callclassA()     {
    $area1=0;
    $classA = new Square();
    $area1 = $area1 + $classA->area();
}
```

This doesn't mean the whole will work, but at least you'll not be trying to call a method of a non object.

**Second**, the callclassA() method is creating and filling a variable, but it's returning nothing, and it's not persisting the result in a class variable. It would be better to try something like

```
class Cuboid extends Shapes
{
private $square=null;
private  $area=null;
function __construct($n, $c, $s, $ns)
    {
    parent::__construct($n, $c);   
    $this->square=new Square("Square",  $c, $s, $ns);
    $this->area = $this->square->area();
    }

    public function area()
    {
        return (6* $this->area);
    }
    public function perimeter()
    {
        return (9* $this->area);
    }   
}
```

**Third**: are you sure the perimeter of the cuboid is 9 times the square area? shouldn't be something times the square perimeter?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i seem to be getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$square' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION). so that is the line underneath class Cuboid extends Shapes. thanks
edit: you are right regarding the perimeter... i just added a random value for now because i couldnt get the area working. so though i should aim to get area working first

Comment: my bad. Class vars where lacking visibility. Try now that I prepended "private" to them.

Comment: getting there.. now i am getting an error Missing argument 1 for Square::__construct(),  ---in square class function construct and parent construct in cuboid class..thanks

Comment: oh, in that case you should call the Cuboid constructor with the parameters $s ans $ns. You won't use them for the Cuboid, but will pass them to the Square constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Independent classes shouldn't share data, it's not possible in any sane way. Instead, provide an adapter method to convert from a square to a cuboid:

```
class Square {

    protected $s;

    ...

    public function getSideLength() {
        return $this->s;
    }

}

class Cuboid {

    ...

    public static function fromSquare(Square $square) {
        return new static($square->getSideLength());
    }

}

$square = new Square(...);
$cube   = Cuboid::fromSquare($square);
```

Your code is too convoluted to adapt it in detail, but this gets the idea across hopefully.

Comment: hi, ive updated my main post with edit 3. is that how it should look like. have i done it correctly.thanks